# How to nest MID function in excel?

Tags: excel, formula

Im trying to nest multiple MID functions in one formula. Here is what i got, at the same time im trying to add some text in between &":" them i want another mid function. But not working, any ideas?

```
=MID(A17,13,1)&":"MID(A17,14,3)
```

Comment: @user3326780 What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you fixed your formula it would only print `<result of mid 1>:<result of mid 2>` which I doubt is your desired output. Here is why [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should always be included!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CONCATENATE` function:

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A17,13,1),":",MID(A17,14,3))
```

So you can concatenate multiple conditions using the separator (`,` for English).

Reference: [concatenate-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(A17, 1, 12, TEXT(,)), 2, 0, CHAR(58)), 5)
```

This doesn't use ampersands or quoted strings.